# Redirect to a file outside of the domain Root

Tags: php

I want to give a file to a person based on the users rank so I need to hide the files in a directory which is hidden.

I'm using Plesk and my structure looks like this:

```
api (reachable from https://api.pexlab.net)
cloud (reachable from https://cloud.pexlab.net)
default (reachable from https://pexlab.net)
error_docs
hidden (not reachable)
```

My PHP script is located in:

```
api/hub/Test.php (reachable from https://api.pexlab.net/hub/Test.php)
```

I have tried this:

```
# In Test.php
downloadFile("../../hidden/hub/download/assets/user/main.fxml");

# Function:
function downloadFile($file) {
   if(file_exists($file)) {
       header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
       header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
       header('Expires: 0');
       header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
       header('Pragma: public');
       header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
       ob_clean();
       flush();
       readfile($file);
       exit;
   }
}
```

This method works but I want to redirect to this file (show it) and NOT download it. So I have tried using this:

```
header("Location: ../../hidden/hub/download/assets/user/main.fxml");
```

But this tried to redirect to https://api.pexlab.net/hidden/hub/download/assets/user/main.fxml which is invalid.

Comment: You can't redirect to a file outside the web root. It would be a massive security hole if you could. To solve your issue, just create a file inside the web root that just echos that file without the above download-headers and you should be fine.

Comment: But why works my download function then?

Comment: Because you're doing exactly what I told you to do, but with a bunch of headers that tells the browser to download the file instead of showing it. However, that's not "redirecting" the request. That's using a "proxy" that resides inside the web root that internally reads the file outside of the web root, just like you did with the download (but remove all those headers, which is what makes the file download instead of presenting it). Your code can access files outside, while clients (browsers and such) can not.

Comment: Use `file()` to bring it into a variable as an array, one line per element. Or use `file_get_contents()` to bring it into a variable as one big long string.  Then simply print it out, etc. as needed to the user

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between "viewing" and "downloading" a file is what the browser does with the data. Ultimately, that's in the hands of the user, but the server can indicate what it would like to happen.

I suspect you have copied these lines without really understanding what they do:

```
   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

These are all instructions to the browser telling it what to do with the data you send.

- The `Content-Disposition` header is used to tell the browser "rather than trying to display this content straight away, suggest the user saves it in a file, with this name". To use the browser's default behaviour, you would simply leave off this header, or give it the value `inline`.
- The `Content-Type` header tells the browser what type of file this is. The value `application/octet-stream` means "just a bunch of bytes, don't try to interpret them in any way". Obviously, that would be no good for viewing a file in the browser, so you should send an appropriate "MIME type", like `text/html` or `image/jpeg`, as appropriate for the file you're serving. I'm guessing "FXML" is an XML-based format, so `text/xml` might be appropriate; or if it's human readable and you just want it displayed without any formatting, use `text/plain`.

Comment: Oh okay. But I don't know how to tell the browser to display the FXML file?

Comment: @DaveGaming Do you mean you don't know what content type to label it as? I've added a couple of guesses to the answer, but you'll have to experiment with what gives the result you want.